# After git_rebase_finish (), the HEAD pointer separately from the master branch

Tags: git-rebase, libgit2

I am making an analogue of Git Pull --rebase using the Libgit2 library, the code is made without errors, but only I have Head in front of Master.

I cannot understand what the problem is.

Here is my code:

```
    error = git_repository_open( &repo, "/tmp/varloc" );
    cout << error << endl;
    error = git_remote_lookup( &remote, repo, "origin" );
    cout << error << endl;
    error = git_remote_fetch( remote, NULL, &fetch_options, NULL );
    cout << error << endl;
    error = git_repository_fetchhead_foreach(repo, fetchhead_ref_cb, &id_to_merge);
    cout << error << endl;
    error = git_annotated_commit_lookup(&heads, repo, &id_to_merge);
    cout << error << endl;
    error = git_repository_head(&head, repo);
    cout << error << endl;
    error = git_annotated_commit_from_ref(&onto, repo, head);
    cout << error << endl;
    error = git_rebase_init(&rebase, repo, (const git_annotated_commit *)heads, NULL, onto, &rebase_options);
    cout << error << endl;
    error = git_signature_now(&me, "Free", "pr070@riseup.net");
    cout << error << endl;
    while((error = git_rebase_next(&op, rebase)) == 0){
        error = git_rebase_commit(&rebaseOID, rebase, NULL, me, NULL, NULL);
    }
    error = git_rebase_finish(rebase, me);
    cout << error << endl;
    git_libgit2_shutdown();
    return 0;
}
```

Git log:

```
commit 4bc03c76474aa0fce8c90ca99f9839eb64f3a67c (HEAD)
Author: FreedomCoder <pr070cryp70n1c@riseup.net>
Date:   Sun Jul 17 22:12:48 2022 +0000

    Add 'tgb'

commit 6ef02ad62c5795d847499452118e38d94013b378 (master)
Author: FreedomCoder <pr070cryp70n1c@riseup.net>
Date:   Sun Jul 17 21:25:46 2022 +0000

    Add 'rfv'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You code is incomplete. I think you may have left out the `void main() {` line and a `#include` for the library you are using. Please [edit] your question and include any other code we may need to help you.

Answer (score 0):

After the rebase is finished, you have to take the last `rebaseOID` and update the branch reference. Something like this:

```
git_branch_lookup(&ref, &repo, "master", GIT_BRANCH_LOCAL);
git_reference_set_target(&newref, ref, &rebaseOID, NULL);
git_reference_free(&newref);
git_reference_free(&ref);
```